# How to set bounties in the Stack Exchange app

Tags: support, android-app, bounties

I often use an app to access SE/SO. Sometimes I see some post on Stack Overflow that didn't get much attention, so I want to use my reputation to set the bounties while I am on an app (Android). I couldn't find the bounty button. Where is the bounty button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Bounty button in app. You need to use web site to offer a bounty to a question.